# react, css) transition css for fade in and out, when background image is changed with className

Tags: css, reactjs, ecmascript-6, transition

I change my className of one div for every 3 seconds(with state change, using setInterval).
And each classes has different background-image.

I want to fade in and out that background images whenever they change, with transition css. I saw some examples for more simple cases, but I have more than two elements to change/ and change pictures with state change.

How can I do that?

I uploaded my code on: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ubxffz
But I cannot upload images on this page so temporarily replaced it to background-color in this page.

this is Image Slide component.

```
const imgUrls = [
    1,2,3
];

class ImageSlide extends Component {

render() {
    const { url } = this.props;
    const Text=...
    return (          
        <div>
            <div className={`pic${url}`}>
                <p className="p1_1">{Text.p1_1}</p>
            </div>
        </div>      
    );
}
```

this is App component, which calls ImageSlide.

```
class App extends Component {
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
        currentImageIndex: 0,
    };
}

// ...

componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.nextSlide(); //this function change the index state. 
        }, 3000);   
}

componentWillUnmount() {
clearInterval(this.interval);
}

// ...

<ImageSlide url={imgUrls[this.state.currentImageIndex]} />
```

this is css for each class, setting background image.

```
.pic1 {
  background-image: url('images/img_01.png');
}

.pic2 {
  background-image: url('images/img_02.png');
}

.pic3 {
  background-image: url('images/img_03.png');
}
```

Comment: can you post code here fork and show us link:https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5zsqnt?file=index.js 감사합니다!

Comment: Thank you. I uploaded it on : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ubxffz. But I cannot upload images on this page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works like this: To fade backgrounds: you need to have two elements with different background-images that are stacked on top of each other and wich then are cross faded

Working code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-talnia).

Working code without framework:

```js
const imgUrls = [
    1,2,3
];
let currentIndex = 0;
const lastIndex = imgUrls.length - 1;

const nextSlide = () => {
  currentIndex++;
  currentIndex = currentIndex % (lastIndex + 1)
  
  // @See https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/
  const elm = document.getElementById('root')
    .querySelector('[class^="pic"],[class*=" pix"]');
  elm.className = `pic${currentIndex+1}`
  const newone = elm.cloneNode(true);
  elm.parentNode.replaceChild(newone, elm);
}

interval = setInterval(() => {
  console.log()
  nextSlide(); //this function change the index state. 
}, 3000);
```

```css
#root {
  position: relative;
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
}
#root .front,
#root .back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#root .front {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
}
#root .back {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}
#root [class^="pic"] .front,
#root [class*=" pic"] .front {
  -webkit-animation: in 3s 0s;
          animation: in 3s 0s;
}
#root .pic1 .front,
#root .pic2 .back {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/640/480?image=1");
}
#root .pic1.init .back {
  background-image: none;
}
#root .pic2 .front,
#root .pic3 .back {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/640/480?image=2");
}
#root .pic3 .front,
#root .pic1 .back {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/640/480?image=3");
}

@-webkit-keyframes in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="pic1 init">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Every code on this platform (stackexchange) is under [Creative Commons licence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/licensing) and [CC-BY SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)

Comment: instead of having two images on top of each other and animating their opacity, is it possible to do it by changing display of a specific image? so lets say i have 3 images that switches every 3 seconds, non active ones will have ```display:none```. Would this still work? @yunzen

Comment: @ertemishakk You cannot animate `display` property. So it's not possible in the way you want

Answer (score 2):

Use `animation` to each class as below:

[See working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-juvxev?file=style.css)

**화이팅!!**

```
.pic1 {
  background-image: url('images/img_01.jpg');
  animation: fade 3s infinite;
}

.pic2 {
  background-image: url('images/img_02.jpg');
  animation: fade 3s infinite;
}

.pic3 {
  background-image: url('images/img_03.jpg');
   animation: fade 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0%,100% { opacity: 0 }
  50% { opacity: 1 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with react hooks

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const heroImage = ["hero1.svg", "hero2.svg"];

export default function Home() {
  const [activeIndex, setactiveIndex] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      currentImageIndex === 0 ? setactiveIndex(1) : setactiveIndex(0);
    }, 3000);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <img
        className={styles.featureImage}
        src={"img/" + heroImage[activeIndex]}
        alt={"imageTitle"}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And CSS will look something like this

```
.featureImage {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  animation: fade 3s infinite;
}
```