# How to dynamically add/remove classNames in react using material-ui?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

How can I dynamically add/remove classes to img tag. Basically I want to change my image automatically after every 2 seconds just like Instagram signup page. But I don't know how to do it using material-ui approach. Here is my code I want to add certain classes and remove them periodically.

```
<div className={classes.phoneImageWrapper}>
  <img src={Phone1} alt="instagram" className={classes.phoneImage} />
  <img src={Phone2} alt="instagram" className={classes.phoneImage} />
  <img src={Phone3} alt="instagram" className={classes.phoneImage} />
  <img src={Phone4} alt="instagram" className={classes.phoneImage} />
  <img src={Phone5} alt="instagram" className={classes.phoneImage} />
</div>
```

and here is my styles I want to add/remove phoneImageAnimation and phoneImageVisible to img after every 2 seconds

```
phoneImageWrapper: {
  margin: "10px 0 0 151px",
  position: "relative",
},
phoneImage: {
  top: 100,
  left: 0,
  position: "absolute",
  width: 240,
  height: 427,
  opacity: 0,
  visibility: "hidden",
},
phoneImageAnimation: {
  transition: "opacity 1.5s ease-in",
  zIndex: 2,
},
phoneImageVisible: {
  opacity: 1,
  visibility: "visible",
}
```

[image: Instagram Signup page]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `setInterval` inside `useEffect` hook. Like this.

```
 const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);

 const images = [
   <img src="/1.webp" alt="1" />,
   <img src="/2.png" alt="2" />,
   <img src="/3.webp" alt="3" />
 ];

  useEffect(() => {
    let timer = setInterval(() => {
      setActiveIndex((prevIndex) => {
        return (prevIndex + 1) % images.length;
      });
    }, 2000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);
```

And for animation you can use [react-transition-group](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition)

I've created an example for you. [codepen_link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-snowflake-7jjsd?file=/src/App.js:76-98)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped. But can you please suggest how to add fading animation to the exiting image. Now the new image appears and the last image is replaced instantly. How can I add fading effect(like decreasing the opacity) before new image is shown. I tried to keep another state variable to keep track of last active index and add className of phoneImageAnimation styles defined in styles.js of material-ui to my div tag but that doesn't work. How to handled it whether it's possible through react-tansition-group?

Comment: Also can you please suggest how to do it without creating separate style.css file. I have defined all my styles using JSS in style.js using material-ui api. I want to add phoneImageAnimation class to the existing image(last active index).

Comment: Actually the fade effect used on instagram is a special kind of effect. I'm sorry but i've no clear idea how to do that exact effect. And you can create a js object for styles and apply them in the div where all the dynamic classes are added.

Comment: You can check this post for some information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55509418/react-css-transition-css-for-fade-in-and-out-when-background-image-is-changed

Answer (score 0):

You can use [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) library. This a handy helper which is specifically for this.

Create a state `image` which rotates between each image (index or name) every 2 seconds

```
<div className={classes.phoneImageWrapper}>
  <img src={Phone1} alt="instagram" 
       className={clsx(classes.phoneImage, image==0 && classes.phoneImageVisible )} />
  <img src={Phone2} alt="instagram" 
       className={clsx(classes.phoneImage, image==1 && classes.phoneImageVisible )} />
  <img src={Phone3} alt="instagram" 
       className={clsx(classes.phoneImage, image==2 && classes.phoneImageVisible )} />
  <img src={Phone4} alt="instagram" 
       className={clsx(classes.phoneImage, image==3 && classes.phoneImageVisible )} />
  <img src={Phone5} alt="instagram" 
       className={clsx(classes.phoneImage, image==4 && classes.phoneImageVisible )} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` and `useState` to change the state of the class.

Lets say you have an array of classes you want to change every 2 seconds:

```
const classes = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

Then, you have a state which is the index of the current className:

```
const [i, setI] = useState(0);
```

And on `useEffect` you start the interval and change the state of the index:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => setI((i+1) % classes.length), 2000);
});
```

The only thing you need now is to use the classes array in the `className` as follows:

```
<div className={classes[i]}></div>
```

And you're done!